# BottomSheetScaffold how add floatingActionButton

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I cannot add floatingActionButton to go up with sheet. How this implement? Now BottomSheetScaffold desn't has property like floatingActionButton. I need to put this to content I think. But how? Now my code looks like this:

```
 BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetSwipeEnabled = bottomSheetState.bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Expanded,
    topBar = {},
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
       
        here sheet content
    }
) { innerPaddingValues ->
  
        AndroidView( here osm map )
}
```

I tryed to put AndridView i box but it doesnt work. Can someone give me a tip?

Im using material design 3

Comment: I think in Material3, BottomSheetScaffold has removed FAB option.

Comment: Any replacement then to this?